# Parsing XML with Python - Accessing Values

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have recently got a RaspberryPi and have started to learn Python.  To begin with I want to parse an XML file and I am doing this via the `untangle` library.

My XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<weatherdata>
  <location>
    <name>Katherine</name>
    <type>Administrative division</type>
    <country>Australia</country>
    <timezone id="Australia/Darwin" utcoffsetMinutes="570" />
    <location altitude="176" latitude="-14.65012" longitude="132.17414" geobase="geonames" geobaseid="7839404" />
  </location>
  <sun rise="2019-02-04T06:33:52" set="2019-02-04T19:16:15" />
  <forecast>
    <tabular>
      <time from="2019-02-04T06:30:00" to="2019-02-04T12:30:00" period="1">
        <!-- Valid from 2019-02-04T06:30:00 to 2019-02-04T12:30:00 -->
        <symbol number="9" numberEx="9" name="Rain" var="09" />
        <precipitation value="1.8" />
        <!-- Valid at 2019-02-04T06:30:00 -->
        <windDirection deg="314.8" code="NW" name="Northwest" />
        <windSpeed mps="3.3" name="Light breeze" />
        <temperature unit="celsius" value="26" />
        <pressure unit="hPa" value="1005.0" />
      </time>
      <time from="2019-02-04T12:30:00" to="2019-02-04T18:30:00" period="2">
        <!-- Valid from 2019-02-04T12:30:00 to 2019-02-04T18:30:00 -->
        <symbol number="9" numberEx="9" name="Rain" var="09" />
        <precipitation value="2.3" />
        <!-- Valid at 2019-02-04T12:30:00 -->
        <windDirection deg="253.3" code="WSW" name="West-southwest" />
        <windSpeed mps="3.0" name="Light breeze" />
        <temperature unit="celsius" value="29" />
        <pressure unit="hPa" value="1005.0" />
      </time>
    </tabular>
  </forecast>
</weatherdata>
```

From this I would like to be able to print out the `from` and `to` attributes of the `<time>` element as well as the `value` attribute in its child node `<temperature>`

I can correctly print out the temperature values if I run the Python script below:

```
for forecast in data.weatherdata.forecast.tabular.time:
  print (forecast.temperature['value'])
```

but if I run

```
for forecast in data.weatherdata.forecast.tabular:
  print ("time is " + forecast.time['from'] + "and temperature  is " + forecast.time.temperature['value'])
```

I get an error:

```
print (forecast.time['from'] + forecast.time.temperature['value'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Can anyone advise how I can correctly access these values?

Comment: Show the output of `print(type(forecast))`

Comment: @stovfl inside the loop it shows `<class 'untangle.Element'>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forecast.time` should be a list, as it does have multiple values, one for each `<time>` node.

Did you expect `forecast.time['from']` to automatically aggregate that data?

Comment: ah ok thanks, so `print ("time is " + forecast.time[0]['from'])` gives me the first value. So in Python how do I iterate through all e.g. `forecast.time[*i*]['from']`?

Comment: `for forecast in data.weatherdata.forecast.tabular.time:
          print (forecast['from'], forecast.temperature['value'])`

Comment: uh, sorry, it's late here :)